# Can not set Luminati proxy on Selenium in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, proxy

I am setting up proxy for Firefox driver with Selenium on Python.

I followed this instruction to setup the proxy: https://github.com/luminati-io/api/blob/master/python/3.x/simple.py

```
username = 'lum-customer-CUSTOMER-zone-YOURZONE'
password = 'YOURPASS'
port = 22225
session_id = random.random()
super_proxy_url = ('http://%s-session-%s:%s@zproxy.luminati.io:%d' %
(username, session_id, password, port))

proxy = Proxy({
    'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
    'httpProxy': super_proxy_url,
    'ftpProxy': super_proxy_url,
    'sslProxy': super_proxy_url,
    'noProxy': '' # set this value as desired
    })


print(proxy)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = "./bin/geckodriver", proxy=proxy)
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

But it 's seem that the proxy is not work. I am always can connect to the site even if I setup a wrong use/password and host url for the proxy.

Did I missed something?

Any idea is appreciate. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution by myself, then I push it here for brothers who need it:

From geckodriver v0.19.1, they remove socketUsername and socketPassword. Therefore we can not use "http://username-sessionid-:passwords@zproxy.luminati.io:port" anymore.

Solution are: save username and password to firefox profile and retrieve it.
Or we can enter password and username when firefox ask it as bellow:

class SeleniumWebDriver:

```
# Set proxy url and proxy port via proxy_url
def get_proxy_cabability(proxy_url):
    desired_capability = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX

    desired_capability['proxy'] = {
        "proxyType": "manual",
        "httpProxy": proxy_url,
        "ftpProxy": proxy_url,
        "sslProxy": proxy_url,
        "socksVersion": 4
    }

    return desired_capability

#get driver
def get_driver(proxy_url):

    desired_capability = self.get_proxy_cabability(proxy_url)
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=desired_capability, log_path=log_path)

    return driver

def set_auth_proxy(username, password):
    try:
        # Force driver show authentication dialog
        self.driver.get('http://www.google.com/')

        # Waiting for alert
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
            ec.alert_is_present())
        alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()

        # send auth information
        alert.send_keys(username + Keys.TAB + password)
        time.sleep(3)
        alert.accept()
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception("Can not authenticate proxy server")
```

Answer (score 0):

I use chrome and get success.

```
import random
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import ProxyType, Proxy

username = 'x'
password = 'x'
port = 22225
session_id = random.random()
super_proxy_url = ('http://%s-session-%s:%s@zproxy.luminati.io:%d' %
                   (username, session_id, password, port))

proxy = Proxy({
    'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
    'httpProxy': super_proxy_url,
    'ftpProxy': super_proxy_url,
    'sslProxy': super_proxy_url,
    'noProxy': ''  # set this value as desired
})

print(proxy)

# driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./bin/geckodriver", proxy=proxy)

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path='/Users/youjunliang/PycharmProjects/chromedriver',
    # options=options
)
# driver.get('https://www.google.com')
driver.get('https://www.amazon.com')
time.sleep(2)
driver.quit()
```

Can you test?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! From my question, I am asking for Firefox. In chrome, I have no problem,but with Firefox I can not do it

Comment: The lines in which you provide chromeOptions are commented out. I tried to run this example (with my credentials) and uncommenting the line options=options and the browser displayed "No internet connection". Is this example indeed accessing webpage over proxy?